# regular expressions corresponding to printf format

Tags: regex, printf

I can imagine somewhere there must be a sort of reqular expression table which corresponds to printf format like as %d, %f, %02x...
Please let me know if you know where it is or you have.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

you mean something like this :
[printf params](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

just look for printf parameters in google

Comment: The question asks for regular expression equivalents.